# How do I insert the output of rake in Textmate

Tags: rake, textmate

I've been using Vim for rails app dev.
I am trying to use Textmate.

I have a rake task which generates some text.
How do I insert the output of the rake to the current file?

I do ":r !rake some_task" in Vim.
What's the equivalent for Textmate?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this belongs on SO, but here's an answer anyway.

Use the `Filter Through Command...` menu item in the `Text` menu. For input, select `None` and output, select `Insert as text`. The command should be your rake command.